# Navigate form immediately in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm developing a project via c# winforms.
I have a problem with navigate to between forms.

I'm using classic form navigation.

when i clicked a button on my main form, there will open a new form which is have so many items on it.

here is codes i used.

```
frmMuayAnaEkran frm = new frmMuayAnaEkran();
frm.ShowDialog();
```

So problem was form creating is too slow. Really, it tooks 8-10 sec for open. 
How can i resolve this problem ? 
Here is form screen which is i want to open it : http://j.mp/VRMyby

Comment: Do you open this form once per application run? Or you want to open it multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's say you have the following things to do on form load :

```
void LoadStartupItemsAndDataBlahBlah(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int s = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
            for (int k = 0; k < 1000; k++)
               s++;
    MessageBox.Show(s.ToString());
}
```

if you call this method in form load

```
private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Stopwatch t = new Stopwatch();
    t.Start();
    LoadStartupItemsAndDataBlahBlah(null,null);
    t.Stop();
    this.Text = string.Format("[{0}] mili-seconds", t.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

your form runs after about 5 seconds (5000 mili-seconds) along with a message box showing `1000000000`

but if you run the method on background

```
private void Form5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker bg = new BackgroundWorker();
    bg.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(LoadStartupItemsAndDataBlahBlah);
    Stopwatch t = new Stopwatch();
    t.Start();
    bg.RunWorkerAsync();
    t.Stop();
    this.Text = string.Format("[{0}] mili-seconds", t.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

your form loads very fast in about 0-1 mili-seconds, and in 5 seconds the message box will arrive and show it's values `1000000000`

Comment: hi i used BackgroundWorker but now form cannot open via dialog. I'm using Showdialog() but form opening like Show().

Comment: @TheMuyu let me check it up, BRB in a few minutes.

Comment: sure mate. also when i closing main form chield form still running :)

Comment: are you using MDI parent/child forms? It's working fine for me, except that I'm using two simple forms

Comment: my main form is Devexpress Ribbon form and other form is normal form. just trying .ShowDialog() method on ribbon page control button.

Comment: also problem is, when i create and showing a form via BackgroundWorker  and when i close form with right corner button form still running on background.

Comment: I've neither worked with nor have access to `Devexpress` components, but as far as .net Forms are concerned, calling `.ShowDialog()` works fine in your case, can you explain what happens exactly that you feel it is like `.Show()`?

Comment: Now I got your point, you have declared your form and showed it in the background worker, yeah?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21942/discussion-between-mahdi-tahsildari-and-themuyu)

Answer (score 4):

I guess that the problem comes from the fact that you are performing some expensive operations inside the form constructor or inside the FormCreated event. Maybe you are querying a database or some remote services. There are a couple of things you might consider:

- Perform the expensive operations on a background thread. For example you could use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx). This will not make the data appear faster, it will just provide a better user experience as the form will show immediately and the data will appear later, not blocking the main UI
- Optimize the expensive operations. For example if you are performing SQL queries you might want to look through a SQL profiler whether those queries could be optimized somehow. It's incredible how much faster a SQL query could run by putting indexes on some columns. If you are performing HTTP requests to fetch the data you could think whether the number of those requests could be reduced - it's usually better to send fewer requests that return more data over the wire rather than many requests with small data.
- You could cache the result of the expensive operation in-memory so that the next time the user opens the same form, he wouldn't need to wait that much in order to retrieve those results.
- Depending on the architecture of your application and the navigation workflow you could start preloading some data before the user actually has navigated to the form. Of course that should be done once again on a background thread to avoid freezing the main worker thread.